# Assigning value to self in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following class in Ruby:

```
class TOMatrix < Matrix
   def initialize
     self = Matrix.build(8, 8){|r, c| 0}
   end
```

But, this gives the error:

```
 Cannot assign to a keyword
```

Does anyone know how to achive what a I need ?

Comment: Are you looking for `super.build ...`?

Comment: Yeah, you can't assign `self` in ruby. It's out of your reach.

Comment: "how to achive what a I need" - and what would that be?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev "you can't assign self in ruby." That sounds like a dare. Couldn't you extend something to enable a self= method?

Comment: @Dmitri: I dare you to try :)

Comment: Several classes (including `String`, `Array` and `Hash`) have a `replace` method that may meet your needs. For example, `str = 'cat'; str.replace('dog'); str #=> 'dog'`. Alas, `Matrix` is not one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the value of self directly. You probably want to do something like this:

```
class Matrix     # I defined it so that people can test the code right away
    def initialize
        @rows = []
        self
    end

    def build rows = 0, columns = 0    #Use your own version of build instead
                                       # It should modify Matrix instead of returning a new one

        @rows = Array.new(rows, Array.new(columns, 0))
    end
end

class TOMatrix < Matrix
    def initialize
        super.build 8, 8    #Initializes Matrix and calls build on it
    end
end
```

Comment: What's the point of "self" in your initialize method for the Matrix class?

Comment: @Dmitri The code doesn't work without it. I've been trying to figure out what is wrong so that I can remove it. For some reason build is being called on rows if I delete self.

Comment: @SlySherZ that is because ruby has implicit returns. the last line provided is the result function. so if you're calling super in intialize, the result of `Matrix`'s initialize is what you are calling `build` on. Just call `build` on the next line after `super` instead of chaining

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to write a wrapper instead of subclassing the Matrix (subclassing in your case might break Liskov's substitution principle):

```
require 'matrix'   

class TOMatrix
  def initialize
    @matrix = Matrix.build(8, 8){|r, c| 0}
  end

  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    @matrix.send(*args, &block)
  end

  def respond_to?(method)
    super || @matrix.respond_to?(method)
  end
end

m = TOMatrix.new
m.hermitian? #=> true
```

Comment: Cool! I've not seen `method_missing` used like that. Very useful!. Elaboration is needed for the OP and many readers. You've been AWOL.